# Aligning two divs next to each other

Tags: html, css

Okay, so this is probably me overlooking something basic, but I've been struggling with getting these two divs aligned properly next to each other. This is how it looks now, and optimally, 'well' would be aligned horizontally with the tabs, but I can't for the love of me figure out why it's floating on top like that.

[image]

Here's my CSS:

```
#wellnum {
    float: left;
}

#wells {

}

#wellwrapper {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="wellwrapper">
    <div id="wellnum">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#well">1</a>
            </li>
            @for (int i = 2; i < 13; i++)
            {
                <li>
                    <a href="#well">@i</a>
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="wells">Well</div>
</div>
```

Any hints?

Comment: Add float left to #well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove the `margin` used in `nav-tabs` or `ul`

Check the snippet below..

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
}
#wellnum {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}
#wellwrapper {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wellwrapper">
  <div id="wellnum">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#well">1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#well">2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#well">3</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#well">4</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#well">5</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="wells">Well</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add bellow css

```
#wells {
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/avgocvg8/2/

Answer (score 0):

You should try like this to make inline your both section -

```css
*{margin: 0;padding:0;}
#wellnum {
 float: left;
}
#wellnum  ul li{
 float: left;
 list-style: none;
}

#wells {
 float: left;
}

#wellwrapper {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wellwrapper">
    <div id="wellnum">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#well">1</a>
            </li>
            @for (int i = 2; i < 13; i++)
            {
                <li>
                    <a href="#well">@i</a>
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="wells">Well</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want your items aligned horizantally, just use:

```
.nav li {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
#wellnum {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/rsgpf64d/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try floating wells as well and using clearfix on the parent.

```
#wellnum {
  float: left;
}

#wells {
  float: left;
}

#wellwrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  zoom: 1;
}

#wellwrapper:before,
#wellwrapper:after  { content: ""; display: block; clear: both; height: 0; visibility: hidden; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
*{margin: 0;padding:0;}
.clearFix { clear:both;}
#box {
    float: left;
}
```